# idTabs - Switching tabs with an anchor within a tab

Tags: javascript, jquery, tabs

I am using idTabs to control the tab content on my page.
I have the normal tab menu across the top and tabbed content underneath.
In the first tabbed content I have an anchor which, when clicked, needs to switch to tab number 2. Here is the example HTML:

```
<div id="practice-menu">
    <ul class="tabs">
        <li><a href="#practice-info-content">Practice information</a></li>
        <li><a href="#practice-treatment-content">Our treatments</a></li>
        <li><a href="#practice-team-content">Meet the team</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>

<div id="practice-info-content" class="tab-content">
    <h2 class="section-title">Practice information</h2>
    <a href="#practice-treatment-content">See our treatments and costs</a>
</div>

<div id="practice-treatment-content" class="tab-content">
    <h2 class="section-title">Our treatments and costs</h2>
</div>

<div id="practice-team-content" class="tab-content">
    <h2 class="section-title">Meet the team</h2>
</div>
```

Here is a Fiddle of the tabs with the anchor in place but its not swtiching the tab across: https://jsfiddle.net/uLy39osc/

I have searched and searched and cant find an answer for this that works with idTabs. Does anyone know how this can work?

Comment: can you please ad a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net)?

Comment: can you provide your javascript code ?

Comment: Fiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/uLy39osc/

Answer (score 0):

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <style>
    body {font-family: "Lato", sans-serif;}

    ul.tab {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    background-color: #f1f1f1;
    }

     /* Float the list items side by side */
    .tab li {float: left;}

    /* Style the links inside the list items */
    ul.tab li a {
    display: inline-block;
    color: black;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    transition: 0.3s;
    font-size: 17px;
    }

    /* Change background color of links on hover */
    ul.tab li a:hover {
    background-color: #ddd;
    }

    /* Create an active/current tablink class */
    ul.tab li a:focus, .active {
    background-color: #ccc;
    }

    /* Style the tab content */
    .tabcontent {
    display: none;
    padding: 6px 12px;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    border-top: none;
    }
    </style>
    <body>

    <p>Click on the links inside the tabbed menu:</p>

    <ul class="tab">
    <li><a href="#" class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'London')">London</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'Paris')">Paris</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'Tokyo')">Tokyo</a></li>
    </ul>

    <div id="London" class="tabcontent">
    <h3>London</h3>
    <p>London is the capital city of England.</p>
    </div>

    <div id="Paris" class="tabcontent">
    <h3>Paris</h3>
     <p>Paris is the capital of France.</p> 
     </div>

    <div id="Tokyo" class="tabcontent">
     <h3>Tokyo</h3>
     <p>Tokyo is the capital of Japan.</p>
    </div>

<script>
function openCity(evt, cityName) {
    var i, tabcontent, tablinks;
    tabcontent = document.getElementsByClassName("tabcontent");
    for (i = 0; i < tabcontent.length; i++) {
        tabcontent[i].style.display = "none";
    }
    tablinks = document.getElementsByClassName("tablinks");
    for (i = 0; i < tabcontent.length; i++) {
        tablinks[i].className = tablinks[i].className.replace(" active", "");
    }
    document.getElementById(cityName).style.display = "block";
    evt.currentTarget.className += " active";
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Sorry. I couldn't get this to work. I'm looking at having an anchor within a tab content which switched the tabs.

Answer (score 0):

Ok so managed to get this working.
So basically I added a click event on the anchor in the tab content which took the href, matched it to a href of the tabs menu then triggered a click on that anchor. Works well!

```
$('.tab-switch').click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var hash = $(this).attr("href");
    if (hash) $('.tabs li a[href$="'+hash+'"]').trigger('click');
});
```